# How to access the flink web UI when running inside a container (wsl2)

Tags: windows, apache-flink, wsl-2

In the First Steps instructions for flink, it says you can connect to the web UI via a local host [link](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/try-flink/local_installation/#:%7E:text=You%20should%20be%20able%20to%20navigate%20to%20the%20web%20UI%20at%20localhost%3A8081), I have been searching for a way to make this work on Windows 10, when running inside wsl2. I followed all steps from the linked First Steps page, but the connection is refused every time.

Answer (score 12):

I did eventually figure this out. If you edit the ./conf/flink-conf.yaml file and change:
`rest.bind-address: localhost` to `rest.bind-address: 0.0.0.0`

then stop and restart the cluster, I can now access the web UI via http://localhost:8081